# the dispatchDraw method and mapViews (android)

Tags: android, android-mapview, draw

i am currently experimenting with my first mapactivity and have extended my own subclass of mapview to override the default dispatchDraw method. my understanding is that it is only possible to do things like limit a user's zoom, etc. by catching changes in the dispatchDraw. my question is this: since dispatchDraw is called just prior to the actual drawing, is it possible to cancel a draw from within the dispatchDraw method? perhaps i'm not wording this well.

example:
user is looking at map and zooms out to level 17. my dispatchDraw method is called and checks to see if the zoom has changed. i find that the user has zoomed out to level 17 but i do not wish to allow them to zoom to this level. can i stop the draw from taking place and reset the zoom? my current method resets the zoom but the draw occurs so there is a zoom animation that takes place which i am hoping to avoid.

Thanks! let me know if you need to see the code

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, as I can not see your method: do not call super.dispatchDraw ?